# Xcode 10.1 highlighting off by one (or more) lines in Version Editor for storyboard file

Tags: xcode10.1, xcode10.2

When I use Version Editor to compare changes, or when committing changes, the changed lines are showing incorrectly (each one is showing offset by one or more lines). Typically I only experience this when opening my storyboard file, rather than code files. Does anyone know the cause and/or how to fix? Thanks

EDIT: This issue persists for me in Xcode 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I discovered what had been causing this for me. I had been putting carriage returns into strings in interface builder using CTRL-RETURN, when I should have been using OPTION-RETURN to do so. Changing those removed the issue for me. Still I think this is something that could be handled in a more forgiving and user-friendly way by Xcode.